# Is there anyway to run a merge result pipeline in bitbucket using bash script?

Tags: git-merge, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to check and validate if the merge to master was a good one or bad one so I want to trigger the pipeline to check the merge requests after it is merged to a master branch.

- Pipeline should trigger atomically once a PR is merged
- pipeline should be successful if the merge is a good onw
- pipeline should fail if the merge is bad
  [New to DevOps] Any other solutions are likely appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work? Running a pipeline for any new commit in the master branch is a pretty basic and standard feature depicted in any bitbucket-pipelines 5' tutorial, I can't tell whether I didn't understand the question or you are utterly astray. E.g do you want the pipeline not to run for direct pushes or something? Why would you?

Answer (score -3):

Read thru the Bitbucket pipeline documentation https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines/

> Pipeline should trigger atomically once a PR is merged

It is possible to run a set pipeline when you do a merge.

> pipeline should fail if the merge is bad

Any pipeline can be made to fail, if the step's scripts are made so they can return an error code if they run into issues. You just need to make the steps to check what could have gone wrong. Bitbucket PR page will tell you before you merge if there are conflicts.

Comment: Can't see how this answers the question.